# What is ResourceProxy class supposed to do?

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

I wonder how this class work.

There isn't any constructor. I think it is here that we can modify the drawer, but I don't know *how.*

Class related to **->** [osmdroid-android](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/ResourceProxy.java)

Lot of thanks, there isn't any specific documentation about this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since osmdroid is a jar, we can't embed resources in it (at least that was the case when osmdroid was first developed). So the ResourceProxy is a solution to provide a "resource set" that is used throughout the app. You can create your own class from this and provide custom resources (like different languages, icons, etc...).